# What do i select in “installation type” when installing ubuntu to dual boot with windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 22.04, disk

There was no “install alongside another OS” so i resized my windows 11 partition and now have 100gb of free space, so i selected the “something else” in the installer and now im confused if i should create the 3 ( i think?) partitions here and if so what should be their types sizes and mount points all help appreciated. Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS (default installer) for a desktop with Nvidia gpu and AMD cpu. Fastboot is disabled and secure boot enabled.

Comment: You've not provided specifics on what Ubuntu product/release you're asking about, as Ubuntu has various ISO choices which include different installers. Your question reads like you're asking about a Desktop ISO with `ubiquity` installer but it's best if you actually tell us & not make us guess. If windows is hibernated (inc. fastboot enabled) or for a few other reasons, you won't have the *install alongside* option show.  Please provide product & release details in questions (and it's best to include ISO details so we know which installer you're using)

Comment: @guiverc edited the post now thanks for clarifying

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS still isn't complete; there are Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS Server (using `subiquity`), Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop (using `ubiquity`) & many *flavors* of Ubuntu (using `ubiquity` with/without skins or `calamares`) also available  (an *alternate* ISO using a *canary* installer was also available but you likely don't mean that, as its not easy to find for a valid reason) . The *default* installer is selected by the ISO you download, so providing that *detail* is what I actually meant.  You likely mean an *amd64* architecture box, but it's best if all details are provided for us.

Comment: you are right the iso i downloaded is  20.04 LTS not 20.04.1 i thought it was the latter because in the “try ubuntu” desktop was a “install ubuntu 20.04.1” for whatever reason

Comment: There is more than just the release details itself (eg. 22.04 = 2022.April release, 20.04 = 2020.April release), but the Desktop/Server, eg. `ubuntu-22.10-live-server-arm64.iso` tells me it's the live Server ISO (thus `subiquity` installer) for 22.10 for *arm64* architecture. 20.04 is two years older than the 22.04 mentioned in your question (20.04.5 is the latest 20.04 ISO both for server/desktop & other options)